# Angular resource/resolve delay causes undefined errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a resource returned from the resolve param of my route:

```
resolve: {
  item: function(Orders, $route) {
    return Orders.get({ id: $route.current.params.id });
  }
}
```

Item basically looks like:

```
var item = {
  name: 'John',
  products: [{
    id: 123
  }, {
    id: 234
  }]
}
```

Now in my controller I watch this:

```
app.controller('ViewOrderCtrl', function($scope, item) {
  $scope.item = item;
  $scope.$watch('item.products', function(n, o) {
    // This yields: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$scope.item.products.forEach')
    $scope.item.products.forEach(function(product) { });
  }, true);
});
```

I am fairly certain the issue is caused by the fact that the resource is not yet consumed so is undefined on load - i.e. doing `console.log($scope.item.name)` will yield undefined as well.

Is there a way to address this issue **without** doing a presence check in my watch. Meaning I am quite aware I can do:

```
if($scope.item.products) {
  $scope.item.products.forEach(function(product) { });
}
```

I would like to know if there is some setting/technique to specifically address this delay issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just to point it out:
[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider)

> resolve - {Object.=} - An optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller. If any of these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected **before the controller is instantiated**. If all the promises are resolved successfully, the values of the resolved promises are injected and $routeChangeSuccess event is fired. If any of the promises are rejected the $routeChangeError event is fired. The map object is:

Comment: That's weird because my experience has been that it's not resolved in the controller - if I console.log($scope.item.name) it will be undefined yet shows fine in the view

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a presence check, but you can use the `newValue` and `oldValue` arguments in the watch function for that.

```
$scope.$watch('item.products', function(n, o) {
    // n is the new value of "$scope.item.products"
    if (n) {
        n.forEach(function(product) {});
    }
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Whisher pointed out:

> If any of these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for
>   them all to be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is
>   instantiated.

Key thing being **promises**. Try:

```
resolve: {
  item: function(Orders, $route) {
    return Orders.get({ id: $route.current.params.id }).$promise;
  }
}
```